# hyperledger-fabric "Writing your first Application" query.js step fails

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

Steps "git clone...", "startFabric.sh" and "npm.install" complete with no errors. "node query.js" results in:

```
    Set wallet path, and associate user  PeerAdmin  with application
    error: [Client.js]: Failed to load user "PeerAdmin" from local key value store. Error: TypeError: this is not a typed array.
      at Function.from (native)
      at importKey (/home/peter/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/impl/CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.js:180:26)
      at fromString (/home/peter/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/User.js:228:28)
      at /home/peter/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:968:22
    error: [Client.js]: Failed to load an instance of requested user "PeerAdmin" from the state store on this Client instance. Error: TypeError: this is not a typed array.
      at Function.from (native)
      at importKey (/home/peter/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/impl/CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.js:180:26)
      at fromString (/home/peter/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/User.js:228:28)
      at /home/peter/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:968:22
   Caught Error [TypeError: this is not a typed array.]
```

Note: after the git clone step, there is no "chaincode" in fabric-samples/fabcar as stated in the docs, but there is a chaincode/fabcar in fabric-samples. This does not seem to cause a problem.
Note: All steps in "Building Your First Network" complete with no problems.

Comment: Peter, thanks for the question. Can you please provide additional information about your environment? What version of Node are you running? Which operating system and what version? I just ran fabcar sample without issue.

Comment: node 4.2.6, npm 3.10.10, running on ubuntu xenial

Comment: Installed node version 6.11.1 and re-ran. New error:

Comment: module.js:597
          return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                                  ^
Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 46.

Comment: You should try deleting node_modules tree and re-run npm install.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 has been tested against Node.js version >= 6.9 and < 7.x. If you get a similar error, recommend updating the version of Node.js (or use a version manager such as nvm) and re-try. If you have already run `npm install` with an older version of Node, you should delete the node_modules tree and re-run `npm install` to be sure you are installing the correct dependencies.