# query.js crash on Hyperledger fabric fabcar example

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

The `fabcar` example of the hyperledger tutorial crashes for me at the step of attempting to run `query.js`.

I have removed all hyperledger related docker images (with docker rmi), so all required content was downloaded automatically when running `startFabric.sh`. The output on startup looks slightly "clouded" but not very suspicious (I skipped the lengthy output about the images being downloaded):

```
# wait for Hyperledger Fabric to start
# incase of errors when running later commands, issue export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=<larger number>
export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=10
#echo ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}
sleep ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}

# Create the channel
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
flag provided but not defined: -e
See 'docker exec --help'.
```

The next step as asked is

```
npm install
```

It also delivers mostly ok output,just one warning:

```
npm WARN fabcar@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

I have verified images are running (also shows that the user is authorized to use the docker, while the user is otherwise *not* root):

```
docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
9acf0dd8a2e2        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.0      "peer node start"        20 seconds ago      Up 19 seconds       0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
da42dca3cbda        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.0.0   "orderer"                20 seconds ago      Up 19 seconds       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
0265c3cd86f2        hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.0.0        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-ser"   20 seconds ago      Up 20 seconds       0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.example.com
4f71895a78c0        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-1.0.0   "tini -- /docker-entr"   20 seconds ago      Up 19 seconds       4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb
```

When I finally try to run

```
node query.js
```

I observe the following errors:

```
Create a client and set the wallet location
Set wallet path, and associate user  PeerAdmin  with application
Check user is enrolled, and set a query URL in the network
Make query
Assigning transaction_id:  eb03c5e69259b880433861daf57a5ac2d33e41d93cebe80a7a478a1aa2cba711
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: Endpoint read failed
    at /home/hla/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:434:17
returned from query
Query result count =  1
error from query =  { Error: Endpoint read failed
    at /home/hla/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:434:17 code: 14, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } }
Response is  Error: Endpoint read failed
```

My OS:

```
uname -a
Linux uhost 4.4.0-92-generic #115-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 10 09:04:33 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174054/hyperledger-fabric-writing-your-first-application-query-js-step-fails) but my node.js version is correct:

```
node --version
v6.11.2

npm -- version
{ fabcar: '1.0.0',
  npm: '3.10.10',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  http_parser: '2.7.0',
  icu: '56.1',
  modules: '48',
  node: '6.11.2',
  openssl: '1.0.2l',
  uv: '1.11.0',
  v8: '5.1.281.103',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }
```

Also, the error message is completely different. The machine has ports 8080 and 8443 in use, but when I tired to shut down the applications using them, was not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you didn't follow the steps.. as it says, before query.js u should enroll the admin and register user, then it works properly. And don't pay attention to "npm WARN fabcar@1.0.0 No repository field", it works well. Try the following:

```
$docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
$docker ps -qa|xargs docker rm
$./startFabric.sh
$cd fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript
$node enrollAdmin.js
$npm install
$node registerUser.js
$node query.js
```

[[image: Output result should look like this[1]]